# Python - How to access first value of every entry

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has a weird structure; each key has multiple values which contain lists or strings itself:

```
{'Q0': {('a', 'Q1'), ('b', 'Q1')}, 'Q1': {('', 'Q2'), ('a', 'Q2'), ('b', 'Q2')}}
```

How do I access the first value of every entry? For example for 'Q0' I want to access the letter 'a' and b, how do I do this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the expected output? Do you want to get `['a', 'b']` as the result? Or a dict like `{'Q0': ['a', 'b'], 'Q1': ['', 'a', 'b']}`? Or something else?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear because we have 3 answers that produce 3 different outputs, _and_ a comment from the OP asking for more code because an answer didn't do what they want. This question is in dire need of clarification.

Comment: @Motambe Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use unpacking:

```
d = {'Q0': {('a', 'Q1'), ('b', 'Q1')}, 'Q1': {('', 'Q2'), ('a', 'Q2'), ('b', 'Q2')}}
new_d = [a for a, _ in d['Q0']]
```

Output:

```
['b', 'a']
```

Edit: pairing the values in the sets:

```
new_data = [[i for i in b] for _, b in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[[('a', 'Q2'), ('', 'Q2'), ('b', 'Q2')], [('b', 'Q1'), ('a', 'Q1')]]
```

Comment: How do you print out the second value of each entry, I need this one as well, because the two are linked. (thank you for the reply btw)

Comment: @MotambeMarkumbo Note that sets are ordered, thus, what appears to be the second value in each set in the input will not be the second value when the code is interpreted. Can you clarify what the criteria is for the second value?

Comment: the first value(a for example), is linked to the second value(Q1 for example). I need it in a way that it is possible to say if(condition) == a, then some variable = value 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = {'Q0': {('a', 'Q1'), ('b', 'Q1')}, 'Q1': {('', 'Q2'), ('a', 'Q2'), ('b', 'Q2')}}
>>> for i,j in a.iteritems():
...     print "First entries for " + str(i) + " : "
...     for k in tuple(j):
...             print k[0]
... 
First entries for Q1 : 
a

b
First entries for Q0 : 
b
a
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of one liner:

```
input_dict = {'Q0': {('a', 'Q1'), ('b', 'Q1')},'Q1': {('', 'Q2'), ('a', 'Q2'), ('b', 'Q2')}}
from itertools import product
output = [i[1][0] for i in list(product(*input_dict.values()))]
print output

Out[89]: ['b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
```